# Two appointments a week php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have the following situation:
A patient is allowed to make 2 online appointments a week from today.

My code is:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
$datum1 = date("d-n-Y");
$datum2 = date("d-n-Y", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($datum)) . " +7 days"));
$query = "SELECT * FROM afspraken WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND datum BETWEEN '$datum1' AND '$datum2'";
```

The query with values:

```
SELECT * FROM afspraken WHERE user_id='2' AND datum BETWEEN '24-4-2012' AND '01-5-2012'
```

Still PhpMyAdmin gives 0 results whilst there are more then 10 records.

```
id  user_id datum   begintijd   opmerking
55  2   24-4-2012   9:30    Deze afspraak is online gemaakt.
56  2   24-4-2012   10:00   Deze afspraak is online gemaakt.
```

Does someone see whats wrong in my queries?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (i) What is the datatype of the `datum` column (ii) why are you specifying date as `24-4-2012` instead of `2012-4-24`?

Comment: `24-4-2012` is not a valid YYYY-mm-dd date.  What's MySQL supposed to do with that?  :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude date representation errors by leaving it to MySQL.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM afspraken WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND datum BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)";
```

In general you probably need format 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Another thing: your code is vulnerable for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). They are nicer to read too, and escaping single quotes and backslashes in string fields etcera.

Answer (score 0):

From the MYSQL Doc:

> For best results when using BETWEEN with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

I would try casting the dates as DATE MySQL datatype in your `WHERE` clause.

So change you query to:

```
SELECT * FROM afspraken WHERE user_id='2' AND datum BETWEEN CAST('24-4-2012' AS DATE) AND CAST('01-5-2012' AS DATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

For first check if in your database the field 'datum' is a date field.
Replace your query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM afspraken WHERE user_id='2' AND datum BETWEEN '24/4/2012' AND '01/5/2012'
```

Comment: I changed the  field datum into a date, which was a varchar. I also made all the dateformats into y-m-d format. Thanks guys